# How do I force the react-i18next t function from useTranslation to infer a language?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next

I am using the following packages:

```
"i18next": 23.5.1
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-i18next": 13.4.1
"typescript": 5.0.2
```

I have initialized i18next like so (i18n.ts):

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import enContent from "./translations/en.json";

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    debug: true,
    lng: "en",
    resources: {
        en: { translation: { ...enContent } },
    }
});
```

I have created a type file (i18next.d.ts) to generate typings for my json files like so:

```
import 'i18next';
import enContent from './translations/en.json';

declare module 'i18next' {
    interface CustomTypeOptions {
        resources: {
            en: typeof enContent;
        };
    }
}
```

Example contents of ./translations/en.json:

```
{
    "common": { "loadingText": "Loading..." }
}
```

When I use the useTranslation hook from react-i18n in my project, I am getting a type error. Example component:

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export const MyComponent = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    return (
        <div>{t("common.loadingText")}</div>
    );
}
```

Error Message:

```
Argument of type '["common.loadingText"]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[key: TemplateStringsArray | "en:common.loadingText" | (TemplateStringsArray | "en:common.loadingText")[], options?: TOptionsBase & ... 1 more ... & InterpolationMap<...>] | [key: ...] | [key: ...]'.
  Type '["common.loadingText"]' is not assignable to type '[key: TemplateStringsArray | "en:common.loadingText" | (TemplateStringsArray | "en:common.loadingText")[], options?: TOptionsBase & ... 1 more ... & InterpolationMap<...>]'.
    Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
      Type '"common.loadingText"' is not assignable to type 'TemplateStringsArray | "en:common.loadingText" | (TemplateStringsArray | "en:common.loadingText")[]'. Did you mean '"en:common.loadingText"'?ts(2345)
```

No matter what I do, I can't get the t function to infer what the language is based on the lng property in the init call to i18n. Am I doing something wrong?

Going further - when I use the suggested parameter ("en:common.loadingText"), the UI does not render the text, but insteaad renders the key because it cannot find the value so I know this is a typing issue...